# Non existence of skew-symmetric matrices with the difference of their square is diagonal of some type

Tags: linear-algebra

By using Maple I can show that there is no  skew-symmetric matrices $J_1$ and $J_2$ of order 4 satisfying
$$J_1^2-J_2^2=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}-\frac12Trace(J_1^2)&0&0&0\\
     0&\frac12Trace(J_2^2)&0&0\\0&0&-1 &0\\0&0&0&-1\end{array} \right).$$
I guess that there is a more elegant proof of this fact using some properties of skew-symmetric matrices I don't know.

Comment: Maybe this can provide you some information : http://www.bealto.com/geo-projective_asymmatrix.html ; the fact that the determinant is the Pfaffian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian can hopefuly play a rôle...

Comment: Think you very much for taking the time to give such elaborated answer. I will read it carefully and may be come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrices are real, we may argue as follows. Since $J_1^2$ is the square of a skew-symmetric matrix, its nonzero eigenvalues must form pairs of repeated non-positive eigenvalues. Therefore, the spectrum must be in the form of $\{-a,-a,-b,-b\}$ for some $a\ge b\ge0$. Similarly, the spectrum of $J_2^2$ is $\{-c,-c,-d,-d\}$ for some $c\ge d\ge0$. So, the equation in question can be rewritten as
$$
J_1^2=J_2^2+\operatorname{diag}\left(a+b,\,-c-d,\,-1,-1\right).\tag{1}
$$
Denote the trailing principal $3\times3$ submatrices of $J_1^2$ and $J_2^2$ by $A_3$ and $C_3$ respectively. Then $(1)$ implies that
$$
A_3=C_3+\operatorname{diag}\left(-c-d,\,-1,-1\right)\preceq C_3-mI_3,\tag{2}
$$
where $-m=\max\{-c-d,\,-1\}$. Also, by the interlacing inequality for bordered matrices (cf. Horn and Johnson, *Matrix Analysis*, theorem 4.3.8 on p.185 in the 1st edition or theorem 4.3.17 on p.242 in the 2nd edition), we have $\lambda_\min(A_3)=-a$, $\lambda_\max(A_3)=-b$, $\lambda_\min(C_3)=-c$ and $\lambda_\max(C_3)=-d$. Therefore $(2)$ gives
$$
\begin{cases}
-a\le-c-m,\\
-b\le-d-m.
\end{cases}\tag{3}
$$
Take traces on both sides of $(1)$, we get $-2(a+b)=-2(c+d)+(a+b)-(c+d)-2$, i.e.
$$
a+b=c+d+\frac23.\tag{4}
$$
So, by adding up the two inequalities in $(3)$, we obtain $-m\ge-\frac13$. It follows from the definition of $m$ and from $(4)$ that
\begin{align}
m=c+d&\le\frac13, \tag{5}\\
a\le a+b=c+d+\frac23&\le1. \tag{6}
\end{align}
We now claim that
$$
d+1>a.\tag{7}
$$
Suppose the contrary that $d+1\le a$. From $(6)$, we also have $a\le1$. Since $a$ and $d$ are nonnegative, this is possible only if $a=1$ and $d=0$. But then by $(6)$ again, we must have $b=0$ and $c=\frac13$, which is a contradiction to $(3)$ (which implies that $b\ge d+m=d+(c+d)\ge c$). Thus $(7)$ must hold.

Next, denote by $A_2$ and $C_2$ the trailing principal $2\times2$ submatrices of $A_3$ and $C_3$. By the interlacing inequality,
\begin{align}
\left[\lambda_\min(A_2),\lambda_\max(A_2)\right]
\subseteq\left[\lambda_\min(A_3),\lambda_\max(A_3)\right]&=\{-a,-b\},\tag{8}\\
\left[\lambda_\min(C_2),\lambda_\max(C_2)\right]
\subseteq\left[\lambda_\min(C_3),\lambda_\max(C_3)\right]&=\{-c,-d\}.
\end{align}
In turn,
$$
\left[\lambda_\min(C_2-I_2),\lambda_\max(C_2-I_2)\right]
=\left[\lambda_\min(C_2)-1,\lambda_\max(C_2)-1\right]
\subseteq[-c-1,-d-1].\tag{9}
$$
We now arrive at a contradiction: by $(1)$, $A_2=C_2-I_2$. Therefore $\left[\lambda_\min(A_2),\lambda_\max(A_2)\right]$ must coincide with $\left[\lambda_\min(C_2-I_2),\lambda_\max(C_2-I)\right]$. Yet, $(7),(8)$ and $(9)$ show that this is impossible, because the two intervals are disjoint. So, we conclude the equation in question is not solvable.

Comment: Think you very much for taking the time to give such elaborated answer. I will read it carefully and may be come back to you.

Comment: I am reading this proof and there is a step I canno't understand. The claim that $m=c+d\leq\frac13$ is clear but I cannot understand why $c+d=\frac13$. I am missing some thing.

Comment: @MohamedBoucetta You are right. I have made a careless mistake. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I think if we put $c+d=\frac13-\alpha$ and $a+b=1-\al$ and pursue the same steps you have done we can get a contradiction. I will check that.

Comment: @MohamedBoucetta Hope it's fixed now.

Comment: It fix it since if I havent made a mistake we get $$
 \begin{cases}
 \left[\lambda_{\min}(A_2),\lambda_{\max}(A_2)\right]
 \subseteq\left[-\frac23,-\frac13+\alpha\right],\\
 \left[\lambda_{\min}(C_2-I_2),\lambda_{\max}(C_2-I_2)\right]
 =\left[\lambda_{\min}(C_2)-1,\lambda_{\max}(C_2)-1\right]
 \subseteq\left[-\frac43+\alpha,-1\right],
 \end{cases}$$ and we can see that the two intervals are still disjoint. Thank you one more for this beautiful idea.

Comment: It fix it since if I havent made a mistake we get $$
 \begin{cases}
 \left[\lambda_{\min}(A_2),\lambda_{\max}(A_2)\right]
 \subseteq\left[-\frac23,-\frac13+\alpha\right],\\
 \left[\lambda_{\min}(C_2-I_2),\lambda_{\max}(C_2-I_2)\right]
 =\left[\lambda_{\min}(C_2)-1,\lambda_{\max}(C_2)-1\right]
 \subseteq\left[-\frac43+\alpha,-1\right],
 \end{cases}$$ and we can see that the two intervals are still disjoint. Thank you once more for this beautiful idea.